# Ethereum node wont sync on Widows 10, transferred eth through shapeshift and it wont show up in wallet

Tags: blockchain, wallets

I recently created an ethereum wallet through the latest update of mist/ethereum wallet off github. I also transferred some decred through shapeshift into my ethereum wallet on the account. I'm very worried I've lost my funds.

However, the node wont sync. At one point, it displayed "4,465,185 blocks out of 4,465,035) and still wouldn't display my funds.

I tried deleting the chainlink directory from the appdata folder but that didn't work. Just made me restart the block downloading process.

I'm very new to the blockchain and don't have adequate programming knowledge. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I especially want to access my funds and know they're still available.

Thank you.

Comment: Cross check your wallet address at etherscan.io, if the balance displays there, then nothing to worry

Answer (score 1):

***How to check your wallet without running a node?***

If you have your address, you can look at it on `etherscan.io`.
There is absolutely no risk doing that, since your address is on-chain
and so is already public information.

***How to spend your funds without running a node?***

There are ways. one of them is to use `myetherwallet.com`.
However, there are **huge risks** doing so.
It is not that `myetherwallet` is not to be trusted 
(I'm not saying you should trust them, just many do without known issue),
but at some point, you will have to send your private key to their website.
If it is *really* their website, that's okay, but it may as well be a fake one.
Then all your money on this particular address will be lost.
I'm not saying you should not use myetherwallet, but be very careful.